Pydantic does not give precedence to os environment
I am tyring to implement proper environment variable management across dev, prod and staging environments. Using Pydantic is critical since  Pydantic is everywhere in the application.
Testing this application becomes challenging due to the setting of os-based environment variables under production and dev environements.
I have the following:
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict

from devtools import debug


class Config(BaseSettings):

    # Environment
    STAGE: str = Field('prod', validation_alias='STAGE')
    OTHER: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file='.test.env', env_file_encoding='utf-8', env_prefix='DEV_')


settings = Config()

debug(settings)

with a .test.env file that looks like this:
STAGE=test
DEV_OTHER="other"

and I set an OS environment variable as follows:
export STAGE=dev

giving the following response with printenv:
...
STAGE=dev
...

and then get the following output:
test.py:18 <module>
    settings: Config(
        STAGE='test',
        OTHER='other',
    ) 

In Pydantic, the OS environment variable will take precedence, but this is not happening here since the setting of environment variables in the dev environment is process-related.
This leads to unexpected behaviour with Pydantic Settings. Is there a workaround?  I do not want to set STAGE in a bash file and restart the environment (which normally means restarting the computer) whenever I want to test behaviour under different environments.

If you aren't loading the .test.env file to the actual environment variables, they won't be present there. The pydantic BaseSettings class only loads the file and parses the content to a pydantic object. It does not modify the environment variables. It also does not load from them.

OK, not sure I follow.  The .test.env file is loaded since I can access all its values through the Config() object. I also have a STAGE variable declared as an OS env variable that is also present in .test.env.  According to the Pydantic documentation I expect the former to take precedence, but it does not.


"Even when using a dotenv file, pydantic will still read environment variables as well as the dotenv file, environment variables will always take priority over values loaded from a dotenv file."



Sorry, my mistake. You're right, pydantic loads and prioritizes values from environment. But I actually can't reproduce your issue. On my machine, the env-variable gets prioritized. Are you 100% sure, that the environment variable is present at runtime? Could you test e.g. print(os.getenv("STAGE"))?

How are you running Python? Are you sure that the python process is inheriting the environment ariables? What if you put import os; print(os.environ) at the top of the file?

Yeah, this is weird.  os.environ.get('STAGE') returns None, yet printenv returns STAGE=prod even with export STAGE=prod which should make the variable available to all subprocesses. Even if I close all python related processes, export the variable and restart the python process, still nothing.

I dig how all three of the "this question is answered here...." answers are completely unrelated to the question. I swear to god man... moderation in this place.

And so you just added the fourth unrelated topic to this post, six months after the fact. Well done, @Shayne.  Comments like these keep me off this platform as far as possible.

The issue is not Pytdantic-related, but the visibility of environment variables and the respective processes in which they are created, as alluded to by juanpa.arrivillaga and lord_haffi. A variable created via export in a shell is only available to that shell and any subprocess of that shell. It needs to be persisted through adding to ~/.zshrc or similar before it will be available to other processes.

Traditionally, .zshrc and similar are the right place for things that aren't passed through the environment (like PS1 and other non-exported shell configuration). The traditional UNIX way says that environment variables go in .profile / .zprofile / etc so they're set only once at login shell creation and not rerun for every interactive shell created as a subprocess of that login shell.
